# S3 bucket and object access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

As per my understanding with out giving access, any IAM user can not access the S3 bucket/object. But in my use case I am able to access it.

Am I misunderstood the security policy in S3. 
Here is my use case I have root account in AWS, say root user. And this user created two IAM users,say *Admin* and *Test* users. And root user given *S3FullAccess* permission to both IAM users.

Now I logged in as  Admin and created one Bucket( say *Tes*t). And enabled *"Block all public access "*.

Now with another IAM user still I am able to access Test bucket, even though  " Block all public access " enabled.
Ideally it should not right. The Test user should get access denied permission while accessing Test bucket.
Am I missing anything, any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks
AWS learner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "block all public access" to the bucket is referring to outside your organization, not with the IAM users.

In other words, if your bucket is accessible to the public, then anyone who has access to the objects S3 URL can directly access that object.

You may restrict access to the bucket by using a bucket policy, but it would make more sense to remove the S3FullAdminAccess from the test user in IAM.

Answer (score 0):

> And root user given S3FullAccess permission to both IAM users

This is the reason why your both the users are able to see the bucket as they have the below policy attached with the user :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You remove this policy from the user and you'll see below error :

[image]

Comment: Hi Pacifist_AWS,

right if I remove S3FullAccess to Test user then I can see "Access Denied " Error. But is there any other way to restrict the Test user not to access the other users bucket without removing "S3FullAccess"

Comment: @BabuGali How about you remove S3FullAccess and explicitly provide access to the bucket using bucket policy.